# I can't connect PHP with SQL Server

Tags: php, sql-server

I am creating a connection php file between SQL Server and PHP 8.1.

My code is the following:

```
<?php
    
    $serverName = "Server\MSSQLSERVER, 1433";
    $connectionInfo = array("Database"=>"Name",
                            "UID"=>"User",
                            "PWD"=>"Password";
    $conn = sqlsrv_connect( $serverName, $connectionInfo);

    
    if( $conn ) {
         //echo "Conexión establecida.<br />";
    }else{
         echo "Conexión no se pudo establecer.<br />";
         die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));
    }
    
?>
```

But, I'm getting this error:

> SQL Error: Error information: SQLSTATE: 08001 Code: -1 Message:
> [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 18 for SQL Server]SSL Provider:
> [error:0A000102:SSL routines::unsupported protocol][error:0A0000C7:SSL
> routines::peer did not return a certificate] SQLSTATE: 08001 Code: -1
> Message: [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 18 for SQL Server]Client unable to
> establish connection

What could be the solution?

Comment: you have to escape the backslash from: `Server\MSSQLSERVER` to `Server\\MSSQLSERVER`

Comment: Considering that `MSSQLSERVER` and 1433 is the default port, you don't even need to specify the instance name.

Comment: Have you read the release notes, [ODBC Driver 18.0 for SQL Server Released](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/sql-server-blog/odbc-driver-18-0-for-sql-server-released/ba-p/3169228), yet? Have you followed the advice wrt. the `Encrypt=true` breaking change?